# No Ubuntu login screen via TeamViewer using VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, teamviewer

I have a weird problem.

I have got the following setup: Native OS: Windows 7 x64 SP1 (6.1.7601) running VirtualBox 4.3.28 r100309. I have a virtual OS which is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which is running TeamViewer 10.0.41459. If I remotely access (via TeamViewer) my host OS (Win7), I see the guest OS (Ubuntu) screen maximized, everything looks normal: https://www.dropbox.com/s/da4ajscccqaofb8/ubuntu_via_host.png?dl=0

But if I remotely access the guest OS directly (bypassing the host OS) I cannot get the login screen. The background is there, but the place where I type my password is missing: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxfx5tyfljy504f/ubuntu_direct.png?dl=0

Anybody have any ideas?